# Ubuntu stopped working without apparent reason

Tags: drivers, nvidia, .desktop, xserver, nouveau

I'm pretty new to the Linux System, I've installed Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS and I am more then satisfied. I'm web delevoper,and for the first time in my life everything worked right away.

I installed nvidia driver, because with default drivers video on Amazon was choppy. It worked great, I followed instruction to the letter. For few days everything was fine, and then one they I turned on **my computer my screen was black and I could see only mouse pointer and system error message.** I've read so many forum posts and tried everything.

**I deleted nvidia drivers, installed and reinstalled default drivers, reinstalled desktop and triend some other things.** Nothing seemd to help me, so I came here for help. I have some data and settings I would like to keep.

**After some time console stopped opening and " *CTRL + ALT + T* " or with combination with F1 - F3 still wont open. But I do have acces to recovery mode.**

Any help will be appriciated ? Thank you very much.

**EDIT :**

I downloaded official driver from nvidia site. I have nvidia gtx 960.
My system is dual boot WINDOWS and Ubuntu,
I have 16GB RAM DDR3,
I have Intel i7-4790K and ASUS ROG motherboard.
Windows is on SSD and Ubuntu on HDD, it has its own partition, but windows uses another partition from the same drive as storage.

To remove nvidia drivers I used `sudo apt-get remove --purge "nvidia-*"`.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Nothing, I mean I don't know where to look ? 
And at the start I was getting something aboout Monitor 0 or Display 0,

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, could you [edit] the question  and add more info about your hardware, how did you install the nvidia driver and how did you removed it?

Comment: I added the edit hoppes it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest removing all of the NVIDIA-related packages. This should reset X to use the nouveau driver. This will at least get your graphics back in order to troubleshoot. Here's how to do that:

1. Power off your computer. Then turn it on while holding down the shift key. This will bring up the grub menu. Use the arrow keys and enter to go to " Advanced Options", then the first line ending in "Recovery Mode" (most likely the second line.)
2. Now a menu should come up. Select "Drop to root shell prompt". **This prompt has root access, so be careful**.
3. Mount your home partition with `mount -o remount,rw /`
4. Now, run `apt-get remove --purge "nvidia-*"`. This will remove all packages starting with `nvidia-`, which will include all the drivers.
5. Reboot with by running `reboot`, and pray that nouveau starts properly.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help. But it did something. Now I get error showing once more. " System problem program detected "

Comment: Hmm... What does it say if you click "More Details" on the system error message?

Comment: I can only Cancle or Send Report. There is no option more details.

Comment: If you hit report, then enter you password, sometimes a new window will come up that has a "More Details" button.

Comment: That doesn't happen to me. When I click report the box disappears and nothing appears.

Comment: @ĐorđeRajić Hmm... I'm really not sure what's happening then. This is outside my knowledge base, unfortunately. But you do have your desktop back, no? Before your screen was just black!

Comment: Unfortunately no. Only difference is that now that error box is shown. When I click Cancle or report got to black with mouse pointer.

Comment: thank you for your help. I downloaded a new version of Ubuntu and upgraded via the old one. Everything seems to be working fine and most of the data is present.