# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes without (apparent) reason

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, freeze, swap

I am experiencing random freezes of the OS on Ubuntu 20.04. I have checked online and there are a lot of other people reporting the same issue. However, none of the solutions proposed worked for me.
The only way I can start working again on my laptop is to force a shutdown by pressing the power button. `Ctrl+Alt+F1` does not work.

I have the following configuration

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Kernel Version: 5.10.0-1049-oem

External monitor: Ultrawide monitor Samsung S34J552 (I thought it might be a problem with the external monitor too, since I had problems in the past with ubuntu 18.04 and external monitors that caused the freezing of the OS)

Thanks in advance to anyone who will try to help.

For reference, the following are the most similar questions to my issue:

- [Issue 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759257/ubuntu-stopped-working-without-apparent-reason)
- [Issue 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294971/ubuntu-20-04-random-freezes)
- [Issue 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1322057/ubuntu-whole-system-goes-unresponsive-from-time-to-time)

(none of them helped me solving my issues)

**More details about my system**

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep 'name'| uniq
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10885H CPU @ 2.40GHz
```

```
uname -r
5.10.0-1049-oem
```

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       2.6Gi        26Gi       332Mi       1.7Gi        27Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

```
grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

```
sysctl vm.swappiness 
vm.swappiness = 60
```

```
lshw -c video
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:185 memory:e3000000-e3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:e4080000-e40fffff
```

```
lshw
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
astroteo-hp-zbook-create-g7-notebook-pc
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smp vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 32GiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10885H CPU @ 2.40GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 2703MHz
          capacity: 5300MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp pku ospke md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities cpufreq
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Intel Corporation
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=skl_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:121 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:e3000000-e40fffff ioport:a0000000(size=303038464)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: NVIDIA Corporation
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
                resources: irq:185 memory:e3000000-e3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:e4080000-e40fffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: TU104 HD Audio Controller
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                version: a1
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:17 memory:e4000000-e4003fff
           *-usb
                description: USB controller
                product: TU104 USB 3.1 Host Controller
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0.2
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.2
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: xhci cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:149 memory:b2000000-b203ffff memory:b2040000-b204ffff
           *-serial
                description: Serial bus controller
                product: TU104 USB Type-C UCSI Controller
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0.3
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.3
                version: a1
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nvidia-gpu latency=0
                resources: irq:129 memory:e4004000-e4004fff
        *-generic:0
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: cap_list
             configuration: driver=proc_thermal latency=0
             resources: iomemory:400-3ff irq:16 memory:404e100000-404e107fff
        *-generic:1
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 12
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel_pch_thermal latency=0
             resources: iomemory:400-3ff irq:16 memory:404e111000-404e111fff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:130 memory:e8200000-e820ffff
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: RAM memory
             product: Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             capabilities: cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: iomemory:400-3ff memory:e8214000-e8215fff memory:404e110000-404e110fff
        *-network
             description: Wireless interface
             product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             logical name: wlp0s20f3
             version: 00
             serial: a4:42:3b:75:32:53
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
             configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.10.0-1049-oem firmware=59.601f3a66.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.u ip=192.168.1.20 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
             resources: irq:16 memory:e8210000-e8213fff
        *-serial:0
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:404e10e000-404e10efff
        *-serial:1
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.1
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:17 memory:404e10f000-404e10ffff
        *-communication:0
             description: Communication controller
             product: Comet Lake HECI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: iomemory:400-3ff irq:168 memory:404e10d000-404e10dfff
        *-communication:1
             description: Serial controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.3
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: 16550 cap_list
             configuration: driver=serial latency=0
             resources: irq:19 ioport:5020(size=8) memory:e8217000-e8217fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:e4200000-e81fffff ioport:404a000000(size=67108864)
           *-generic
                description: Unassigned class
                product: RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:131 memory:e4200000-e4200fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:123 ioport:6000(size=12288) memory:b4000000-e20fffff ioport:4000000000(size=1241513984)
           *-pci
                description: PCI bridge
                product: JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018]
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: 06
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=pcieport
                resources: irq:16 ioport:6000(size=8192) memory:b4000000-e1ffffff ioport:4000000000(size=1241513984)
              *-pci:0
                   description: PCI bridge
                   product: JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018]
                   vendor: Intel Corporation
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                   version: 06
                   width: 64 bits
                   clock: 33MHz
                   capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                   configuration: driver=pcieport
                   resources: iomemory:1f10-1f0f irq:125 memory:e1f00000-e1ffffff
                 *-generic
                      description: System peripheral
                      product: JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 4C 2018]
                      vendor: Intel Corporation
                      physical id: 0
                      bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
                      version: 06
                      width: 32 bits
                      clock: 33MHz
                      capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                      configuration: driver=thunderbolt latency=0
                      resources: irq:16 memory:e1f00000-e1f3ffff memory:e1f40000-e1f40fff
              *-pci:1
                   description: PCI bridge
                   product: JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018]
                   vendor: Intel Corporation
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: pci@0000:04:01.0
                   version: 06
                   width: 64 bits
                   clock: 33MHz
                   capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                   configuration: driver=pcieport
                   resources: iomemory:61610-6160f irq:126 ioport:6000(size=4096) memory:cb000000-e1efffff ioport:4025000000(size=620756992)
              *-pci:2
                   description: PCI bridge
                   product: JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018]
                   vendor: Intel Corporation
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: pci@0000:04:02.0
                   version: 06
                   width: 64 bits
                   clock: 33MHz
                   capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                   configuration: driver=pcieport
                   resources: iomemory:1f10-1f0f irq:127 memory:caf00000-caffffff
                 *-usb
                      description: USB controller
                      product: JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 4C 2018]
                      vendor: Intel Corporation
                      physical id: 0
                      bus info: pci@0000:39:00.0
                      version: 06
                      width: 32 bits
                      clock: 33MHz
                      capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
                      configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                      resources: irq:150 memory:caf00000-caf0ffff
              *-pci:3
                   description: PCI bridge
                   product: JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018]
                   vendor: Intel Corporation
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: pci@0000:04:04.0
                   version: 06
                   width: 64 bits
                   clock: 33MHz
                   capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                   configuration: driver=pcieport
                   resources: iomemory:71710-7170f irq:128 ioport:7000(size=4096) memory:b4000000-caefffff ioport:4000000000(size=620756992)
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:124 memory:e4100000-e41fffff
           *-storage
                description: Non-Volatile memory controller
                product: Micron Technology Inc
                vendor: Micron Technology Inc
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:6d:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: storage nvm_express bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nvme latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:e4100000-e4103fff
              *-nvme0
                   description: NVMe device
                   product: MTFDHBA1T0TDV-1AZ1AABHA
                   physical id: 0
                   logical name: /dev/nvme0
                   version: HPS0032
                   serial: UJUNE01ZRELNXK
                   configuration: nqn=nqn.2014-08.org.nvmexpress:1344134420502BF0A376        MTFDHBA1T0TDV-1AZ1AABHA state=live
                 *-namespace
                      description: NVMe namespace
                      physical id: 1
                      logical name: /dev/nvme0n1
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-multimedia
             description: Multimedia audio controller
             product: Comet Lake PCH cAVS
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=sof-audio-pci latency=64
             resources: iomemory:400-3ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:186 memory:404e108000-404e10bfff memory:404e000000-404e0fffff
        *-serial:2
             description: SMBus
             product: Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: iomemory:400-3ff irq:16 memory:404e10c000-404e10c0ff ioport:efa0(size=32)
        *-serial:3 UNCLAIMED
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.5
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:fe010000-fe010fff
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 3
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 4
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          physical id: 5
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
     *-pnp00:04
          product: PnP device INT3f0d
          physical id: 6
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:05
          product: PnP device HPQ8002
          physical id: 7
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
     *-pnp00:06
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 8
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:07
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 9
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:08
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: a
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@6:1.4
       logical name: enxb0227af8d7ca
       serial: b0:22:7a:f8:d7:ca
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.11.11 duplex=half firmware=rtl8153a-3 v2 02/07/20 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Comment: Are you sure the kernel is 5.10?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I just run now the command `uname -r` and got `5.10.0-1049-oem` as an output.

Comment: OEM maybe why I never recognized the kernel number. It is usually 5.4, 5.8 or 5.11 and above and not OEM. Not saying this is wrong just unusual.

Comment: Lots of possible causes for freezing, If a solution for Possible Cause X didn't help you, then it's likely that you have a different cause.

Comment: OEM kernels are normal for newer hardware that don't have all the proper modules in the mainline kernel yet. OEM kernels are transitional -- eventually the system will upgrade to a future fully-supported non-OEM kernel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)